# UWP C# Read and Write from AppData folder

Tags: c#, xml, uwp, directory

i want to read and write something in a XML file located on the Folder "AppData". I tried following Code

```
  private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
          { 
             StorageFolder folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(@"C:\Users\IT\AppData");
             .....
          }
```

But i get only this as result

> "System.UnauthorizedAccessException" Access Denied

So how can i Access the AppData Folder ? Please help me

Comment: See [UWP File access permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions)

Comment: It doesn't answer my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access any location the user has permissions to, you will have to target the Spring Creators Update (1803) and request the [`broadFileSystemAccess` capability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions#accessing-additional-locations). It is not possible for earlier versions of Windows 10, although you could let the user pick the folder manually using `FolderPicker`.

Comment: How can i Traget to Sping Creators Update ? It is not included in my VS.

Comment: You will have to install the preview SDK for now. The final version will be released during April. You will also have to update your PC to the Release Preview version of Windows 10 or wait to the end of April for the official rollout. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windowsinsiderpreviewSDK

Answer (score 0):

UWP is very restricted regarding the file permissions. You cannot access any file except those in you application folder.

See here: [File access permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions)

In future versions of UWP there will be an option to gains systemwide access, which the usere can block...

Comment: so you will say it is not possible to Access this Folder?

Comment: thezapper is right; you wont just get access. To get access the user needs to select it via the File/Folder picker or it has to be in ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder *or one of the other options*. Also for the Libraries *document, music etc* there are options to get access.